# Which regular expression should I use for getting image link from text?

Tags: php

I have following code:

```
<center><img src="http://trustedyouautocorrect.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ixxx66134057.jpg" alt="daniel7531sarah" /></center><input id="gwProxy" type="hidden" />

<!--Session data--><input id="jsProxy" onclick="if(typeof(jsCall)=='function'){jsCall();}else{setTimeout('jsCall()',500);}" type="hidden" />
<div id="refHTML"></div>
```

I need to make script that will get link from image-src. How can I do it? I hope you help me. Thank you.

Comment: And now you have two problems.

Comment: The first problem has not changed. And now you have the problem of creating, verifying, and maintaining the regular expression.

Comment: regex is overkill for a simple task

Comment: Can there be more than one `<img` tags in input?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming with Javascript. Easiest way would be to put an id attribute on the img, then you can extract the src easily.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getSRC() 
    {
        var imgID = document.getElementById("imgID");
        alert( imgID.getAttribute('src') );
    }
</script>


<img id="imgID" src="someIMG.png" /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="getSRC()">get</a>
```

Comment: Question is tagged as php, so assuming that is the required language

Comment: Oh so it is. Just didn't make sense from a PHP view. Since PHP can't access the page after it's loaded, which was what I thought was the question. Ahh well, someone's allways looking for getAttribute code.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to extract the img src...

```
<?php
    $str = '<center><img src="http://trustedyouautocorrect.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ixxx66134057.jpg" alt="daniel7531sarah" /></center><input id="gwProxy" type="hidden" />

<!--Session data--><input id="jsProxy" onclick="if(typeof(jsCall)==\'function\'){jsCall();}else{setTimeout(\'jsCall()\',500);}" type="hidden" />
<div id="refHTML"></div>';

    // regex to match all src attributes of image tags
    preg_match_all("/<img[^>]+src=(['\"])(.+?)\\1/",$str,$matches);
    // $matches{
    //  [0] -> the whole matched string
    //  [1] -> the quotation char (could be ' or ") captured so it can be used
    //          to match the closing quote (of the same type)
    //  [2] -> the src attr value
    // }

    // loop through each src attr value we captured
    foreach($matches[2] as $m){
        echo "This is what you are after ~~> " . $m;
    }
?>
```

Regex means...

- `<img` followed by
- one or more not `>` (`[^>]+`) followed by
- `src=` followed by
- `'` or `"` captured for later use and escaped (`(['\"])`)
- followed by a bunch of stuff un-greedily (`.+?`)
- followed by same quote as captured before escaped (`\\1`)

This is however a bad way to approach the problem, and comes with a few issues. My regex does not capture src attributes that are unquoted. There might also be unusual circumstances where it matches false positives, or does not match real url's.

Regex, although great for many circumstances, as a swiss army knife of matching patterns, it makes a poor parser. Whe you need to parse HTML, you should use the appropriate methods.

A much much better (less error prone, faster, easier to understand and maintain) way to do it...

```
<?php
    $str = '<center><img src="http://trustedyouautocorrect.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ixxx66134057.jpg" alt="daniel7531sarah" /></center><input id="gwProxy" type="hidden" />

<!--Session data--><input id="jsProxy" onclick="if(typeof(jsCall)==\'function\'){jsCall();}else{setTimeout(\'jsCall()\',500);}" type="hidden" />
<div id="refHTML"></div>';

   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str);

   //get img tags
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');

   //loop through found image tags
   for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++){
        $node = $items->item($i);
        if ($node->hasAttributes()){
            // attach all attributes of tag to array
            foreach ($node->attributes as $attr){ 
                $array[$attr->nodeName] = $attr->nodeValue; 
            }
        }
        // print out just the src attribute
        echo "This is what you want ~~> " . $array['src'];
   }
?>
```